# Apache beam python pipeline doesnt proceed after groupbykey()

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am doing a GroupByKey in a pipeline, keys are strings and values are dictionaries. I want to group them and do processing on them.
I am able to reach next step if i remove the GroupByKey, but not with it.

```
(parseout_interim | beam.Map(lambda row: (row['prefix'] + row['report_id'], row))
                                                # | beam.GroupByKey()
                                                | beam.ParDo(ParseSegmentsDoFn()).with_outputs(ParseSegmentsDoFn.OUTPUT_TAG_TRADELINE,
                                                                                              main = 'parseout'))
```

If I comment GroupByKey, data reaches next step.

Am i missing something completely?

Also, on a sidenote - is it advised against spinning up a pipeline inside a ParDo? or it is completely fine? If it is fine, i would get away without having to use groupbykey

Comment: I was reading from PubSub, thats why groupbykey was not working. It was taking an unbounded pcollection and was waiting forever if i am not wrong. I introduced time windowing and now it works as expected.

Comment: I'm glad you figured that out. I posted a small explanation. Let me know if I should give more background.

Answer (score 0):

As you imply in your comment, this must be a Streaming pipeline.

Consider that a streaming pipeline is continuously receiving events. When you want to *group* events within that pipeline, the system needs to know how long it should wait for events to come in while grouping them. Does that make sense?

Because of that, you need to have a windowing and triggering strategy for your pipeline, otherwise it will wait forever, to group all elements in the stream.

Comment: Just to add a nice read that can maybe help other users, one can refer to the Dataflow documentation about [Bounded and Unbounded PCollections](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pcollection#bounded-and-unbounded-pcollections), which despite being deprecated, still can provide a good understanding of some streaming concepts. Just focus on the generic concepts (and how to deal with unbounded data sources using windows and triggers), and disregard the implementation-specific sections, which may have changed on the latest Apache Beam releases.

Comment: Also @Nichole, feel free to accept (and upvote) the answer if it was helpful for you to show the community that this post is solved and may be helpful for other users too.